# How to create a QGLWidget from a CGLContextObj?

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, qt4, core-graphics

I'm using Qt 4.8.4 on Mac OS 10.8.

I already have a `CGLContextObj` (created outside my control).

I would like to create a `QGLWidget` from (or at least shared with) my existing `CGLContextObj` — so I can render the textures which were created on the `CGLContextObj`.

How can I create a `QGLContext` from the existing `CGLContextObj`?

---

#### Already tried

- I found [`QGLContext::fromPlatformGLContext()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglcontext.html#fromPlatformGLContext), but this method appears to only be available when Qt is built in QPA mode (...but `./configure -qpa cocoa` fails to build, and I haven't been able to find any documentation on exactly what the `-qpa` flag does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QPA (Qt Platform Abstraction)](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Platform-Abstraction) was still a work in progress in Qt 4. It's [fully integrated into Qt 5](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/qt-project-list-development/n38gzD0iG9c). If you have the option to upgrade to Qt 5, things might be easier.

In Qt 5, you can construct a `QCocoaGLContext` (a derived class of `QPlatformOpenGLContext`), and from that get a `QOpenGLContext` (`QPlatformOpenGLContext::context()`), and from that get a `QGLContext` (`QGLContext::fromOpenGLContext(QOpenGLContext *)`). That gets you pretty close, but how do you get from a `CGLContextObj` to a `QCocoaGLContext`?

Unfortunately, I don't see an option to construct a `QCocoaGLContext` from a `CGLContextObj`. It does have a `NSOpenGLContext` private data member, which is initialized inside the existing constructor, so maybe you could add another constructor.

Comment: Almost.  Most of the classes you mentioned are private, and thus aren't exposed via the Qt 5 framework API.  I wrote a patch to add public function `bool QOpenGLContext::createWithNativeContext(void *nativeContext)` — https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31294